# Center image in Bulma

Tags: bulma

Is there a way to horizontally centered an image inside a card?

I have the following

```
  <div class='column is-one-quarter has-text-centered'>
    <div class='card equal-height'>
      <div class='card-content'>
        <figure class='image is-64x64'><img src='...'></figure>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

and I cannot center the image. I have tried to add `is-centered` both to the figure and to the parent div but nothing changes.

Thanks.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Change the display property of `card-content` to `flex` by using the `.is-flex` modifier.

Now you can use flexbox properties to horizontally center the `figure`. There is no modifying class for this with Bulma, so you can make your own...

```
.is-horizontal-center {
  justify-content: center;
}
```

Add this to `card-content` and you're done.

```css
.is-horizontal-center {
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.6.2/css/bulma.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class='column is-one-quarter'>
  <div class='card equal-height'>
    <div class='card-content is-flex is-horizontal-center'>
      <figure class='image is-64x64'><img src='https://unsplash.it/64'></figure>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, that just works.
Since I need to add other tags to the card, I ended up to add `is-flex is-horizontal-center` to the `figure` tag otherwise also the other tags would be horizontally aligned with the image.

Comment: I add more flex, it's working for me: 

display: flex;

Comment: I downvoted this answer because, while technically correct, it breaks out of how Bulma works and circumvents the built in modifiers. The correct answer is just simply adding is-inline-block to the image. And everything will flow just right. See the answer from @Merbin below.

Answer (score 68):

Make the `figure` tag an `inline-block` and assign `has-text-centered` to the parent tag. Advantage is no custom code needed.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.6.2/css/bulma.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class='column is-one-quarter'>
  <div class='card equal-height'>
    <div class="card-image has-text-centered">
        <figure class="image is-64x64 is-inline-block">
            <img class="is-rounded" src="https://unsplash.it/64"/>
        </figure>
    </div>
    <div class='card-content'>
      <!-- other content here -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this definitely seems like the best answer to me compared to the others. makes sense and doesn't require custom styles.

Comment: the class 'is-inline-block' is all I needed! Thaanks!

Comment: Thank you, the accepted solution was not working for me as I'm not using a card in my columns and just have a `<figure> <image>` hierarchy. This solution worked for me, cheers!

Comment: This is the answer

Answer (score 13):

You can also use a `.level` element found in the Bulma *layout* section. The level elements are what Bulma uses to assist with specific vertical and horizontal centering of elements such as images and things other than text. You can find more information about it [here](https://bulma.io/documentation/layout/level/).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.7.1/css/bulma.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class='column is-one-quarter has-text-centered'>
    <div class='card equal-height'>
      <div class='card-content'>
<!-- Place image inside .level within your card element -->
        <nav class="level">
          <div class="level-item has-text-centered">
            <figure class='image is-64x64'><img src='https://bulma.io/images/placeholders/128x128.png'></figure>
          </div>
        </nav> 
<!-- And it'll be centered like so -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Note: In order to have multiple elements (i.e. Such as an image and text) horizontally centered *and* vertically centered, all you have to do is place `.level` elements underneath each other:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.7.1/css/bulma.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class='column is-one-quarter has-text-centered'>
    <div class='card equal-height'>
      <div class='card-content'>
        <!-- Place image inside .level within your card element -->
        <nav class="level">
          <div class="level-item has-text-centered">
            <figure class='image is-64x64'><img src='https://bulma.io/images/placeholders/128x128.png'></figure>
          </div>
        </nav>
        <nav class="level">
          <div class="level-item has-text-centered">
            <h1>Title to image</h1>
          </div>
        </nav>
        <!-- And it'll be centered like so -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 12):

**Native** Bulma solution:

```
<div class="columns is-flex is-centered">
    <figure class="image is-128x128">
        <img src="assets/images/logo.png" alt="logo">
    </figure>
</div>
```

Put your code between `columns, is-flex and is-centered div`

Answer (score -2):

You can use the Flexbox helpers: `is-flex` and `is-justify-content-center`

```
...
<figure class="image is-128x128 is-flex is-justify-content-center">
    <img src="assets/images/logo.png" alt="logo">
</figure>
...
```